# Automatically start AppEngine Flexible Server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, app-engine-flexible

Edit: So I found the web.xml `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` tag is what I would need, but apparently it is not supported on flexible. Is there a alternative?

So this is probably a really obvious question, but I couldn't figure it out..

I have a AppEngine Flexible Environment Server, and use this servlet.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet(name = "servlet", value = "/")
public class FirebaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String TAG = FirebaseServlet.class.getSimpleName();
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        FirebaseOptions options = ...
        Log.d(TAG, "debug");
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("Server Running...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        super.destroy();
    }
}
```

So then when I run this command:

```
mvn clean jetty:run
```

It will run on localhost:8080, but I always have to actually open the web browser, and navigate to localhost:8080, and if im already on it, I have to refresh the page everytime I run the jetty:run command. After I go on localhost/refresh it, the servlet starts, initializes firebase listeners and prints *Sysout

```
debug
```

So im sure there is something really obvious im overlooking here, how can I make it automatically start the servlet? So that I dont have to navigate the the localhost webpage, or in case of production, navigate to the appspot page.

And if its needed, this is my App.yaml

```
runtime: java
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
  secure: always

runtime_config:  # Optional
  jdk: openjdk8
  server: jetty9

resources:
  cpu: 0.5
  memory_gb: 0.6
  disk_size_gb: 10

env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: YOUR-BUCKET-NAME=bucketname.appspot.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule tasks using cron.yaml so they automatically start at certain intervals.

See the Google Cloud Platform documentation for more information https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml